# Relative layout disperse on real device

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

In  android studio3.0 in design  tab have this kind of layout [image]

But on real  device i have this crap: [image]

What i do wrong?  Please help.

Comment: stack blocking my code. Posted in answer.

Comment: ok  . let me check. you made  nested linear layouts.  Bro may be you know why the way i made it does not work with  relative layout or may be where to read about it.

Answer (score 0):

the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
        android:id="@+id/view">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_add_todo"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/view"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

        <!--task label-->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TitleLabel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:text="@string/title_string"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
            android:textSize="@dimen/label_size"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/TitleLabel"
            android:hint="@string/enter_title_string"
            android:inputType="textShortMessage"
            android:text=""
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"/>
            <requestFocus />

        <!-- Description -->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/DescriptionLabel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/title"
            android:text="@string/description_string"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
            android:textSize="@dimen/label_size"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/description"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/DescriptionLabel"
            android:hint="@string/enter_description_string"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress|textMultiLine"
            android:lines="10"
            android:minLines="2"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:singleLine="false"
            android:text=""
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge">
        </EditText>

        <!--Deadline time-->
        <!-- Time and Date -->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/time_and_date"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/description"
            android:text="@string/time_and_date_string"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="@color/colorAccent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/date"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/time_and_date"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/time_and_date"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:text="@string/no_date_set_string"
            android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
            android:textSize="20dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/time"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/time_and_date"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/date"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
            android:text="@string/no_time_set_string"
            android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
            android:textSize="20dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/date_picker"
            style="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/date"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/time_and_date"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:text="@string/choose_date_string" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/time_picker"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/date"
            android:layout_below="@id/time"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:text="@string/choose_time_string" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/alarm_me"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/time_and_date"
            android:layout_below="@+id/date_picker"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:text="@string/alarm_me_string"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="@color/colorAccent" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/alarmCheckBox"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/alarm_me"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/DescriptionLabel"
            android:hint="@string/alarm_hint"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"></CheckBox>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/complete"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/alarm_me"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/alarm_me"
            android:layout_below="@+id/alarm_me"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:text="@string/complete_string"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="@color/colorAccent" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/completeCheckBox"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/complete"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/alarmCheckBox"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/DescriptionLabel"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"></CheckBox>


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/cancelButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/completeCheckBox"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/completeCheckBox"
            android:text="@string/cancel_string" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/submitButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/alarmCheckBox"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/cancelButton"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:text="@string/submit_string" />


    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Why do you have `style="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"` for date_picker button?

Comment: i could change it  but i more focused on positions of my elements